# Build c# 6.0 on TFS 2012

Tags: c#, tfs, msbuild, roslyn

How can I build a Visual Studio 2015 solution using C# 6.0 Features at a TFS 2012 without installing Visual Studio 2015 on a build agent (using Microsoft Build Tools 2015 RC)

I Already installed MSBuild Tools but I still get exceptions. How can I Tell my build template to use MSBuild 14 (Only for one project)

And why does my TFS 2012 compile async and await (c# 5.0) without any problems while the BuildAgent only has Visual Studio 2012 installed?

I tried changing the ToolPath of my BuildProcessTemplate to MSBuild/14.0/ but I get a build error:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.CSharp.targets (316): "csc2.exe" exited with code -532462766.

Installing the Microsoft.Net.Compilers 1.0.0-rc2 Compilers gives the same error.

If I compile the project using the command line I get the exact same error / although there is no error on my dev machine when using the command line with the exact same arguments.

This is the Exception I get in the command line:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\csc2.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:TRACE /highentro.....
     Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.
        at System.Collections.Immutable.SecurePooledObject`1.Use[TCaller](TCaller& caller)
        at System.Collections.Immutable.SortedInt32KeyNode`1.Enumerator.PushLeft(SortedInt32KeyNode`1 node)
        at System.Collections.Immutable.SortedInt32KeyNode`1.Enumerator..ctor(SortedInt32KeyNode`1 root)
        at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableDictionary`2.Enumerator..ctor(SortedInt32KeyNode`1 root, Builder builder)
        at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.RuleSet.GetDiagnosticOptionsFromRulesetFile(Dictionary`2 diagnosticOptions, String resolvedPath, IList`1 diagnosticsOpt, CommonMessageProvider messageProviderOpt)
        at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpCommandLineParser.Parse(IEnumerable`1 args, String baseDirectory, String additionalReferencePaths)
        at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpCommandLineParser.CommonParse(IEnumerable`1 args, String baseDirectory, String additionalReferencePaths)
        at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommonCompiler..ctor(CommandLineParser parser, String responseFile, String[] args, String baseDirectory, String additionalReferencePaths)
        at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpCompiler..ctor(CSharpCommandLineParser parser, String responseFile, String[] args, String baseDirectory, String additionalReferencePaths)
        at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CommandLine.Csc..ctor(String responseFile, String baseDirectory, String[] args)
        at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CommandLine.Csc.Run(String[] args)
        at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.BuildClient.RunWithConsoleOutput(String[] args, RequestLanguage language, Func`2 fallbackCompiler)
        at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CommandLine.Program.Main(String[] args)
        at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CommandLine.Csc2.Main(String[] args)
```

Comment: Do you have the .NET Framework 4.6RC installed on the Build server?

Comment: no do I need to ? the solution is working with .net 4.5, and the .net 4.6 RC is a  in place upgrade potentialy breaking other stuff on the Server

Comment: The new Roslyn engine of the compiler framework is built using 4.6. I suspect it needs it to load the assembly.

Comment: Microsoft says Roslyn is based on 4.5 / only requires 4.5 https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/visual-studio-2015-system-requirements-vs#MBT_RC

Comment: Are you using a legacy XAML build agent or a new 2015 agent?

Comment: I am using a legacy build agent. It is running on the same instance as the team foundation server at t he moment.

Comment: You seem to be correct on the 4.5  part. I looked at all the references and it looks like that's true for 2015RC as well. Though the link you provided doesn't really say so.

Comment: @jessehouwing The link says Additional Requirements: NET Framework 4.5

Comment: Try `/p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0` as the MSBuild arguments.

Comment: @DanielMann error remains.

Comment: Any success on this? I'm having the same problem (TFS build 2013, .NET Framework 4.6) and this MoFo doesn't use C#6 compiler anyway.

Comment: I installed VS 2015 on the build agent.And got some more problems Idescribed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31180393/buildactivity-ignores-toolsversion

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I used TFS2013 U5, but it will be same:

- installed VS2015 RTM on BuildServer machine
- put this into MSBuild arguments in Process part of BuildTemplate

> /tv:14.0 /p:GenerateBuildInfoConfigFile=false
>   /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0

Both compiling and VS-unit tests are now running OK.

Comment: Thanks mate! Solved my issue.

Comment: I tried this and I'm still bonking. TFS 2012 Update 3 doesn't care about my build arguments and it also doesn't care that VS 2015 is installed or that MSBuild 14.0 is first in the path. :(

Comment: @MikeCaron Likewise I'm using TFS 2012. Did you solve it?

Comment: Getting this:     ToolsVersion is not valid. The tools version "14.0" is unrecognized. Available tools versions are "2.0", "3.5", "4.0". Switch: 14.0

Comment: People using tfs 2012 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31180393/buildactivity-ignores-toolsversion?lq=1 (You'll also need to make some minor changes to the build process template)

Answer (score 5):

Try using either

```
/p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0
```

or

```
/tv:14
```

In your build arguments

Comment: This won't work alone - you need to change the build definition used. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659106/tfs-2013-building-net-4-6-c-sharp-6-0?rq=1

Comment: It worked fine for me. After adding this build argument, build started working

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Jiří Zídek is correct but it was missing one crucial detail.  I had to do the following to get things working on TFS 2012 Update 2:

1. install Visual Studio 2015 on the build server
2. set the `MSBuild Arguments` in the build definition to `/p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0` (i.e. Visual Studio 2015 mode)
3. in each project that uses C# 6 syntax, install the NuGet package [Microsoft.Net.Compilers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers) `install-package Microsoft.Net.Compilers`

It was #3 that made the difference for me.

Comment: Note that Microsoft.Net.Compilers is to allow Roslyn support when you don't have the latest toolset. So you haven't fixed your issue you've done a workaround meant for older versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand Lex?  For my own case I'm just trying to work around older versions of TFS; not older versions of Visual Studio. If there's something that's missing please do highlight it; but as far as I can tell my own issue is fixed.

Comment: If you are using the VS2015 Toolset (14.0) you shouldn't need that package. Also you may still run into problems with some tooling (such at MSTest). We worked round this on a TFS 2013 Application server by installing the TFS 2015 Agent software (it is backwards compatible).

Comment: Even though VS2015 is installed on the TFS2012 build agent passing /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 alone did not work. The Microsoft.Net.Compilers package installation was still necessary. Maybe there's a key difference between TFS2012 and TFS2013.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you using TFS 2012 and VS 2017 bypassing 2015, you can follow my answer on [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46244952/build-vs2017-project-with-tfs-2012-build-server/47181623#47181623)

[TFS 2012 and VS 2017 continuous integration build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46244952/build-vs2017-project-with-tfs-2012-build-server/47181623#47181623)