# Building Visual Studio C++ solution 2015 failed using TFS 2013 team build

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, tfsbuild

We have TFS build machine configured to build source code from TFS. On this machine we had Team Foundation Server 2013 together with Microsoft Build Tools 2013 installed and then recently, we installed Microsoft Build Tools 2015. In the build defintion, we put /tv:14.0 for MSBuild arguments to indicate we want to use version 14.0 of MSBuild. Also, we set the perform code analysis to be false so that it won't perform code analysis.
However, when we queue a build, it failed with given errors:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\CodeAnalysis\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.targets (214): The source file for this compilation can be found at: "C:\Users\tfsservice\AppData\Local\Temp\b54ca1bb-e696-4214-a196-5c79c32345cd.txt"
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\CodeAnalysis\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.targets (214): An error has occurred during compilation. error CS1705: Assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' uses 'Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\CodeAnalysis\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.targets (214): The "SetEnvironmentVariable" task was not found. Check the following: 1.) The name of the task in the project file is the same as the name of the task class. 2.) The task class is "public" and implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. 3.) The task is correctly declared with <UsingTask> in the project file, or in the *.tasks files located in the "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64" directory.
```

Does anybody experience this issue before?
It seems like the Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core was referenced to the incorrect version of Microsoft.Build.Framework.

However, in MSBuild.exe.config, this assembly is redirected corectlly

```
<dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Build.Framework" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-99.9.9.9" newVersion="14.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

Any helps are appreciated.

P.s. The solution we want to build is a visual c++ solution upgraded from VS 2013 to VS 2015.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that many other community members have the similar issue, the **/tv:14.0** argument doesn't work. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31180393/buildactivity-ignores-toolsversion) for the detailed information.

The workaround is: instead of using the **/tv:14.0** argument, you need to customize the tfs build process template to set ToolPath of the **Run MSBuild for Project** to target to MSBuild14; and set ToolVersion to "14.0".

[image]

Comment: Thank for you suggestion. I'm looking for any solutions not involving in changing process template as it may result maintaining a different build template in source control.