# MSVC 2015 using 2013 Platform Toolset

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build

I have a copy of Microsoft Visual 2015 on a Windows 32 bit Computer. I would like to compile C++ code with a 2013 build set. I have researched this issue, and I am unfortunately very stuck and looking for guidance.

As you can see in my configurations (below), I have options of platform toolset for 2010 and 2008 in addition to the 2015 versions. I have downloaded Visual Studio 2013. Alas, the option does not appear to be added to the toolset choices!

[image: Project Configurations]

My ultimate problem I am trying to solve is an error I get when I build code. Specifically:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol
>   _WinMain@16   TestProject C:\Users\userProf\Desktop\workspace\TestProject\TestProject\MSVCRTD.lib(exe_winmain.obj)
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol
>   __imp__vsnprintf_s    TestProject C:\Users\uperProf \Desktop\workspace\TestProject\TestProject\MSVCRTD.lib(vsnprintf_s.obj)

System Specs:

[image: System Specs]

Some research:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2f2bb34b-f8f2-4316-80e5-fd2b0d237e17/visual-studio-2013-v110-platform-toolset?forum=visualstudiogeneral

[TFS Build 2013 - using Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32889259/tfs-build-2013-using-visual-studio-2015)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The "ultimate" problem seems fairly trivial. You've got a MSVC library in your project directory! That's bound to give version issues. Just remove it; MSVC finds its own libraries in its own install directory.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I ended up finding a copy of 2013 MV Community Studio https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-community-vs.aspx and fired that up. Seemed to fix most of the problems.  This isn't a solution, as I just went around the problem ( so I will not post in answers).