# TFS 2010 issues building C#6.0 code with MS Build 14

Tags: tfs, msbuild

We have TFS 2010 running happily on a dedicated build server.

I have installed Microsoft Build Tools 2015, which includes MS Build 14 successfully on the build machine, but not Visual Studio 2015.

I've created a custom template which alters the "ToolsPath" property of the "Run MSBuild" activity to "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin".

The build runs, but fails on this particular error:

```
(CoreCompile target) -> 
  CSC : error CS1566: Error reading resource 'ProjectName.exe.licenses' -- 
'Could not find file 'C:\develop\Sources\ProjectName\obj\x86\Release\ProjectName.exe.licenses'.' [C:\develop\Sources\ProjectName\ProjectName.csproj]
```

The same project builds fine using Visual Studio 2015 running from another machine.

It makes no difference whether the TFS build definition includes these MS Build arguments or not:

```
/tv:14.0 /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0
```

Does anybody have a success story of using a TFS 2010 build agent to successfully build a C#6.0 project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this in the end by installing Visual Studio 2015!

Answer (score 0):

The `/tv:14.0 /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0` argument  may don't work for MSBuild Tools.

You should customize the tfs build process template to set ToolPath of the Run MSBuild for Project to target to MSBuild14; and set ToolVersion to "14.0".

Check this link for the detailed information:[BuildActivity ignores ToolsVersion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31180393/buildactivity-ignores-toolsversion)