# Visual Studio 2015 with TFS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfsbuild

We recently upgraded SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2014 and since we had DB projects we also had to upgrade Visual Studio from 2010 to 2015 in order to support build and deployment of DB projects from Visual Studio locally.

We are now trying to use Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 with TFS 2010
But I am facing issues with build automation and TFS server

1. When I try to select "Items to Build" I am getting this message box,

   [image]
2. When I try to open the build template I am not able view some of the agent scope,

   [image]

Much appreciate any advice that can help to fix this issue, thanks.

============= UPDATE ========================

I have VS 2010 and VS 2015 installed on same workstation (2010 in primary drive and 2015 in secondary drive), it seems it is pointing to teamfoundation dll's of version 2010.

I manually tried to install Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow of VS 2015 in GAC; this solved my second problem (i.e. no problem in viewing the build template now) but I am still facing same error while selecting "Items to build"

================================

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think build definition change from tfs server version to next because a lot of stuff gets obsolete. You may have to redo them with new templates.

Comment: @Claudius, I have not updated TFS version. TFS version is still 2010 but VS is updated from 2010 to 2015, please check I have updated question with few more details.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I thought is that you may had to amended the build templates to point to **MS Build version 14.0**. Yes, there are two parameters including 'ToolPath' and 'Tool version' to set. For detail, you can reference this link：[BuildActivity ignores ToolsVersion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31180393/buildactivity-ignores-toolsversion)

Answer (score 1):

Patrick answer is partially correct. You vs is pointing to version 14.0 of all TFS builds and lots of stuff from 2010 templates is obsolete. My advice id to download separate vs 2010 on same system or update tfs to 2015 and then redo build definition using vNext.

Pros of tfs 2015 vNext. Nicer, cleaner and will work for next few years.

Pros of vs 2010 vNext. You install vs 2010 and everything works.

Truthfully if you didn't saved any changes since moment your builds that used template last time worked they should still work, regardless of the fact that your vs can't read them.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I think when we upgrade to TFS 2015 your advise will be very useful for me.

Comment: Yes for now I would only download vs 2010 since it will work nicely. Only person responsible for making definition has to have it. Rest can can use vs 2015. it will show errors but build will be successful as long as the definition is right for tfs version.