# Running Builds with C# 6

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-2015, c#-6.0

We recently upgraded to TFS 2015 from 2010. As a result of this upgrade, we wanted to start using `C# 6` syntax in our projects, but whenever we do, the build fails due to syntax errors. The build agents/controllers are also from the TFS 2015 installer (it's a whole new set of servers)

Our builds are using the `TfvcTemplate.12.xaml` Process template, which apparently is the TFS2013 xaml build template.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32262541/2505574) answer, you can modify the template to set the ToolsVersion appropriately, but our template does not have a `Run MSBuild for Project` item, it has a `Run MSBuild` activity, which does not have the indicated properties.

I've also tried setting the `tv:14.0` and `/p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0` arguments on MSBuild from the Build Definition from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32662291/2505574) answer, but this also does not resolve the issue.

What do we need to do in order to get the build to accept `C# 6` syntax?

Comment: On my dev machine I had to resset the settings of my Visual Studio. I don't know why. Maybe a Plugin or Add On or caching.

Comment: A project's build settings include the target language.  You have to change the language version of old projects to C# 6.

Comment: Go to build agent machine, and use MSBuild command to build your project, to see what result you'll get.

Comment: Do you use VS2015 to create C# 6.0 project?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT dammit, this was a PEBKAC, the actual error was from Stylecop.MSBuild, updating the package resolved the issue. Not sure if its worth updating the Q to be more specific, and answer it, or just delete the Question outright?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using VS 2015, then C# 6 should be working out of the box. Try to create a light c# 6.0 project and queue XAML build to check whether the issue from your project or from build server.
2. Before using XAML build, make sure you can have successful build with MSBuild command line manually on build agent server.
3. If you migrate to C# 6.0, check blog [Migrating project to .NET 4.6 and C# 6](http://marisks.net/2015/10/15/migrating-project-to-net46-and-csharp6/) to see whether it is helpful.