# How do I enable C# 7 builds in Team Foundation Server 2015?

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-2015, c#-7.0, visual-studio-2017

We have Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2015 installed on-premises. We would like to use Visual Studio 2017 to take advantage of the latest C# language features. We are not ready to upgrade to TFS 2017. What are the steps required to allow the latest C# language features to build in TFS 2015?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't follow these steps exactly, but based on what I have learned, I think they would have worked:

1. Install [Visual Studio 2017 Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017) on the XAML Build Configuration server
2. Add these lines to the TFSBuildServiceHost.exe.config file:

```html
  <configSections>
    <section name="msbuildToolsets" type="Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ToolsetConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <msbuildToolsets>
    <toolset toolsVersion="15.0">
      <property name="MSBuildToolsPath" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin" />
    </toolset>
    <toolset toolsVersion="latest">
      <property name="MSBuildToolsPath" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin" />
    </toolset>
  </msbuildToolsets>
```

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server
>   14.0\Tools\TFSBuildServiceHost.exe.config
>
> (I never would have figure that out without this
>   [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f3c4fc0b-d9ee-474a-9d91-9c5810b074a2/how-to-get-vs-2017-working-with-tfs-2017-xaml-builds?forum=tfsbuild). Thank you [jonesy2488](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/jonesy2488)!)

3. Restart the XAML Build Configuration service.
4. Change the XAML Build Process Template to include the ToolVersion="15.0" parameter:

```html
<mtba:RunMSBuild DisplayName="Run MSBuild" OutputLocation="[OutputLocation]" CleanBuild="[CleanBuild]" CommandLineArguments="[String.Format(&quot;/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true {0}&quot;, AdvancedBuildSettings.GetValue(Of String)(&quot;MSBuildArguments&quot;, String.Empty))]" ConfigurationsToBuild="[ConfigurationsToBuild]" ProjectsToBuild="[ProjectsToBuild]" ToolVersion="15.0" ToolPlatform="[AdvancedBuildSettings.GetValue(Of String)(&quot;MSBuildPlatform&quot;, &quot;Auto&quot;)]" RunCodeAnalysis="[AdvancedBuildSettings.GetValue(Of String)(&quot;RunCodeAnalysis&quot;, &quot;AsConfigured&quot;)]" />
```

Comment: *Add them to the TOP of the config file, just one level from root :)

Comment: What if you don't use XAML builds anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Just install latest version of Microsoft.Net.Compilers nugget package

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers >> 
.Net Compilers package. Referencing this package will cause the project to be built using the specific version of the C# and Visual Basic compilers contained in the package, as opposed to any system installed version.

This package can be used to compile code targeting any platform, but can only be run using the desktop .NET 4.6+ Full Framework.

Comment: Thanks. I added the original link. @hvd

Comment: I assume you mean install the package on the TFS server?

Comment: No, install it on your c# project as like as other nuget packages you install. You can open your project with visual studio 2015 too! Visual studio will show error for syntaxes introduced in c# 7, but the project itself gets built successfully. This approach works with any msbuild based build including tfs

Comment: In VS 2017 I added the Compilers package and the ValueTuple package to my project. It works locally in Visual Studio. However, when I run it on the build server I get this error: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.CSharp.targets (316): The "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.Csc" task could not be loaded from the assembly E:\...\3\190\src\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.2.0\build\..\tools\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///E:\...\3\190\src\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.2.0\tools\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll'

Comment: yeah, I'll just run through 20+ projects... or I fix it once and for all and use the accepted answer :)