# Updating Visual Studio and TFS from 2013 to 2015

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, updates

We have several .NET solutions (desktop apps and an MVC website) we've been working on. The projects were all built in VS2013 and are hosted on a TFS 2013 server. We would like to update to VS2015...but I'm a little wary about it. If we update to VS2015, do we also need to update to TFS 2015? Or is it smarter to run VS2015 alongside VS2013? If we do the latter option, would be still need to update TFS to 2015?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can quite happily use VS 2015 and TFS 2013 together.

In the olden times (TFS 2010 or earlier) you might have wanted to keep the old version of VS around to manage the TFS server but these days most functions are available from the TFS web UI.

The only thing you would need to be careful with is if you are using TFS Build for your CI server. If this is the case you will need to update the version of VS installed on your build agents.

Comment: Creating team projects requires the same version of TFS and Visual Studio.

Comment: Good point @DanielMann This is one of the few things that you'll need to keep the older version of VS around for.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to update to TFS2015. You can still use VS2015 with TFS2013.

But if you want to build  for C#6/.Net 4.6 applications, you need to pay attention to your build enviroment. Such as install **MSbuild Tools 14.0**, amend the build templates to point to MS Build version 14.0. For detail you can reference:  [TFS 2013 building .NET 4.6 / C# 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659106/tfs-2013-building-net-4-6-c-sharp-6-0)